# With python pandas, how to recover a modded running sequence number?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe, and one of the column contains a modded running sequence number like this: (mod by 8)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3 ...]

And I would want to recover the "un-modded" sequence
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ...]

What's the best way to do this?

What I can think of is to use df.iterrows() to check for discontinuity to increase a "base" value. But since .iterrows() is highly discouraged, so is there a better way to do this?

### Edit 1:

Sorry folks, I didn't state it clear, **some random entries are missing**, so the shape does not perfectly reflect the original un-modded sequence which I attempt to recover.

So it is more like, from raw sequence:

[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3 ...]

to recover:

[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ...]

Comment: how come its 8 and not 16(or 32?) for the first time you go over 8? if its always perfectly sequential why couldnt you just do `range(len(df[col]))`? you cant really reverse it since 0 maps to `0,8,16,32....` you might be able to fake it if you better describe the problem statement

Comment: Why not just simply replace the column, with `frame[col_name] = range(frame[col_name].shape[0])`?

Comment: hi @JoranBeasley, 8 is just for easy illustration, the actual mod I am dealing with is 65536. And it is not a perfect sequence, a few entry are missing.

Comment: Hi @tdihp, sorry I didn't state it clear, some random entries are missing, so the shape does not perfectly reflect the original un-modded sequence.

Comment: When there are gaps, how do you expect to determine the number of missing entries? If the sequence includes `[..., 2, 4, ...]` how is one supposed to know whether one, nine or 8N+1 (for any integer N) have been omitted?

Comment: I think anytime a[n] > a[n+1] you  mod_value(in this case 8) to the offset value

Comment: hi @JoranBeasley, I think so too. Is there a way to do this without iterate through dataframe in pandas?

Comment: hi, @holdenweb, the actual mod I am dealing with is 65536, and my raw data is not likely to continuously miss more than 100 entries.

Answer (score 2):

```
def unmod_series(my_values,mod_value=8):
    i = 0 
    for first,second in zip(my_values,my_values[1:]):
        yield first + i
        if first > second: i += mod_value
    yield second+i


print list(unmod_series([0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3],mod_value=8))         

#result is  [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

I guess would do what you want .... but I think this is essentially the same as iterrows ... I guess you are looking for a vectorized way of doing this ... I doubt you will find one

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about everything. And thank you for the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do this using numpy:

```
import numpy as np


def unmod_array(arr, mod_value=8):
    # when last number is larger or equal to current number, it's a new cycle
    index = np.argwhere(arr[:-1] >= arr[1:]).reshape(-1) + 1
    cycles = np.split(arr, index)
    return np.concatenate(list(arr + i * mod_value for i, arr in enumerate(cycles)))


arr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3])
print unmod_array(arr)

# result is [ 0  2  3  5  6  9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

the performance difference is minor when the array is small,
so if @Beasley 's answer is less confusing, use that.

**UPDATE**

When mod_value is large (such as 65536), there is significant performance difference:

```
>>> arr = np.array(range(65536) * 100)

>>> %timeit unmod_array(arr, 65536)
10 loops, best of 3: 37.8 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(unmod_series(arr, 65536))
1 loops, best of 3: 3.58 s per loop
```

Comment: ahh there is a way to do it with numpy I guess ... is the performance difference still minor with very large lists? I would expect this to work better in the case of a very large list ...

Comment: hi @JoranBeasley I've added %timeit test on large mod values.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to define a generator that produces a sequence of the missing bases, create a `Series` from that sequence, and then add it to the modular column. First attempt:

```
def pieces_of_eight(N):
    for i in range(N // 8):
        for j in range(8):
            yield i
    for j in range(N % 8):
            yield i+1
```

You can create the required `Series` in this way:

```
s = Series(pieces_of_eight(len(dataframe)))
```

Then add that to the modular column.

However, many datasets have a numerical index starting at zero and increasing by one per row. If this column's name were N then you can simply add N//8 to the modular column. I imagine this would be much quicker.

**NOTE: this answered the question as originally proposed, but does not take account of the potential for missing entries.**

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't state the question clear, some rows might be missing, can see my edit.